# SUM mulitple IFs in a query

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have the following query and I get the results as expected:

```
    SELECT
      IF (a1>b1,'1','0') AS a1r,
      IF (a2>b2,'1','0') AS a2r,
      IF (a3>b3,'1','0') AS a3r,
      IF (a4>b4,'1','0') AS a4r,
      IF (a5>b5,'1','0') AS a5r,
      IF (a6>b6,'1','0') AS a6r,
      IF (a7>b7,'1','0') AS a7r,
      SUM(a1r+a2r+a3r+a4r+a5r+a6r+a7r) AS ar
      FROM fab_matches
      WHERE p1 = 12 AND p2 = 15;
```

However I want to produce a single query (possibly with a subquery) to get only the value of 'ar' and not the others.
I know it's easy but I am stuck!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this in a subquery:

```
SELECT a1r, a2r, a3r, a4r, a5r, a6r, a7r,
a1r+a2r+a3r+a4r+a5r+a6r+a7r AS ar
FROM (
  SELECT
  IF (a1>b1,'1','0') AS a1r,
  IF (a2>b2,'1','0') AS a2r,
  IF (a3>b3,'1','0') AS a3r,
  IF (a4>b4,'1','0') AS a4r,
  IF (a5>b5,'1','0') AS a5r,
  IF (a6>b6,'1','0') AS a6r,
  IF (a7>b7,'1','0') AS a7r /*you have to change the alias here, since you already used it in the first line*/
  FROM fab_matches
  WHERE p1 = 12 AND p2 = 15
) subquery_alias;
```

You can not refer to aliases in the same `SELECT` clause.

The order in which a query is processed is

1. FROM
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. ORDER BY
6. SELECT

Comment: Thanks for the subquery. I was stuck in the subquery_alias..:-)

Answer (score 1):

You do not *have* to do it in a subquery, although that is the most common method, this works too:

```
SELECT
    IF (a1>b1,'1','0')
  + IF (a2>b2,'1','0')
  + IF (a3>b3,'1','0')
  + IF (a4>b4,'1','0')
  + IF (a5>b5,'1','0')
  + IF (a6>b6,'1','0')
  + IF (a7>b7,'1','0')  AS ar
FROM fab_matches
WHERE p1 = 12 AND p2 = 15;
```

Each of those IF expressions simply evaluate to a single value, so you can use them directly in arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks for this alternative solution also! This added a value in my small mysql knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

You may do as

```
select 
  SUM(a1r+a2r+a3r+a4r+a5r+a6r+a7r) AS ar
  from (
   SELECT
   IF (a1>b1,'1','0') AS a1r,
   IF (a2>b2,'1','0') AS a2r,
   IF (a3>b3,'1','0') AS a3r,
   IF (a4>b4,'1','0') AS a4r,
   IF (a5>b5,'1','0') AS a5r,
   IF (a6>b6,'1','0') AS a6r,
   IF (a7>b7,'1','0') AS a1r
   FROM fab_matches
   WHERE p1 = 12 AND p2 = 15
 )x ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pleae you can try by this simple way -

```
SELECT 
SUM(IF(a1>b1,'1','0')+IF(a2>b2,'1','0')+IF(a3>b3,'1','0')+IF(a4>b4,'1','0')+IF(a5>b5,'1','0')+IF(a6>b6,'1','0')+IF(a7>b7,'1','0')) AS ar
FROM fab_matches
WHERE p1 = 12 AND p2 = 15;
```